# How do you get Paladin Danse out of his power armour?

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one

I'm asking about Danse specifically, not other companions. I'd completed his personal quest blind betrayal recently, which just ended in me leaving Listening Post Bravo to report back to Elder Maxson, thus finishing the quest. However, to my surprise, when I returned to Listening Post Bravo, he was snuggled up inside a full suit of X-01 power armour, ready to go. Now it isn't every day one comes across one of those models, and I already know how to get other companions out of power armour, but the option for him specifically to exit the suit just isn't there. Is there any way I can get him out and use the armour for myself?

Comment: I can't test this right now to verify, but you may be able to trade lesser power armor components to him and make him equip them, thus freeing up his X-01 components for you to pilfer. Let me know if that works and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't, but I'd need to explicitly test it a bit before I felt comfortable trying to prove the negative. You definitely can't get him out of the T60 he starts in.

Comment: Nukapedia says that "You can supply Paladin Danse with upgraded power armor by transferring it to his inventory and equipping it. With a fully upgraded set of X-01 power armor, this makes him a extremely powerful companion." It's not clear if that results in the armor he was previously wearing becoming available for you to take.

Comment: You can't. I've researched the same on PC, and the only options I found involved using the developer console. (Which is the path I ended up taking)

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back on the comment section above.  You are unable to make Paladin Danse leave his [Awesome] suit of X-01 Power Armor on PS4 or Xbox One.  This was found through a lot of forum digging to include Reddit, GameFaqs, and Girlplaysgame.  You can however make... or rather force, Paladin Danse out of his Power Armor on PC through the developer console.  He has been noted as coming out of his Power Armor as a "Naked Slenderman" or something to that effect BUT after going to sleep he returns to normal and you can have his Armor.  I hope this helps clear things up!